# Defining new infix operators in Raku

Tags: operators, raku

Please tell me how to define a new operator in Raku, for example, how would one implement an arrow operator defined something like this:

```
operator ▶ {my ($left, $right) = @_; $left->{$right}}
```

Comment: https://docs.raku.org/language/functions#Defining_operators

Comment: Readers may not understand the code on the right of the `▶`. A Raku compiler will reject it at compile time. I could edit the question, and plan to, but I instead want to document a related SO editorial notion with this comment. It's Perl code. *Once an answer has been accepted*, a `[perl]` tag might be appropriate, so searchers for answers might find it. If it needed attention from folk who search/monitor the `[perl]` tag for new questions, then adding it now would make sense. But it doesn't, so adding a `[perl]` tag right now is inadvisable as it it will be likely to unduly waste their time.

Comment: raiph: unfortunately, an answer can never be accepted, because the user deleted their account

Comment: @user0721090601 Not exactly. Someone could post a bounty and whichever answer gets the bounty becomes the accepted one.

Comment: @BradGilbert I had no idea!  We've had this problem for a while on Spanish.SE, never knew that that was the solution (although it doesn't help in the few cases we've had where the accepted answer is wrong.  The solution there was to just make a new question and upvote the mess out of it)

Comment: @user0721090601 If you looked at my extraordinarily low user number of 1337, you might realize that I have been on here a long long time.

Comment: It also spells l33t, so cool!

Answer (score 14):

It's fairly simple:

```
sub infix:<▶> ($left, $right) {
  $left."$right"() 
}


# Example: 

class Foo {
  method bar { "hello" }
}

my $a = Foo.new;

say $a ▶ 'bar'
# hello
```

The `sub infix:< >` defines new infix operators (other options are `prefix`, `postfix`, `circumfix`, and `postcircumfix`, the latter two require an opening and closing part, like `<( )>` for open and close parentheses).

The `($left, $right)`, as the name suggests, handle the left and right side values.

To call a method based on an string, you use the structure `." "()` with the method name in quotation marks and followed by parentheses — even if there are no arguments.  In this case, we just insert the variable for basic interpolation, although more complex operations are possible.